How to pause a Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey for more than 14 days?
In Journey Builder, I need to pause a journey for 3 months. However, based on the documentation, it seems that the maximum duration for a paused journey is 14 days, after which the journey automatically resumes or stops.
I'm looking for a workaround to extend the paused duration to the desired 3 months. My initial thought is to manually re-pause the journey every 14 days once it resumes automatically.
My questions are:

Is manually pausing the journey every 14 days the best approach, or are there better alternatives?
Could I stop the journey entirely and later restart it by re-adding the same contacts to a new version of the journey without losing their progress?
Are there any other recommended best practices or creative solutions to handle such a situation in SFMC?

